# Парсит одну страницу два раза подряд C#

Tags: c#, winforms, selenium

Здравствуйте.
Есть метод, который парсит содержимое страницы, а затем получает нужные блоки текста:

```
public void StartParser(string pageSource)
    {
        try
        {
            //Объявляем переменные
            StringBuilder htmlCleaner = new StringBuilder();
            HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument HD = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
            HtmlNodeCollection outputHtml;

            HD.LoadHtml(pageSource);

            //Получим номер текущей страницы
            var menuHtml = HD.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//span[@class='current']");
            if (menuHtml.InnerText == "1") //Если первая страница, то...
            {
                outputHtml = HD.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='reader-text font-size-medium']");

            }
            else //Если не первая, то...
            {
                outputHtml = HD.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@style='display: block; text-align: justify; margin-bottom: 12px;']");
            }

            //Записывает полученную коллекцию в stringbuilder и чистим от тегов <span>, которыми шифруется основной текст
            foreach (var j in outputHtml)
            {
                htmlCleaner.AppendLine(j.InnerHtml);
            }
            string str = htmlCleaner.ToString();
            Regex r = new Regex("<span .+? </span> ", RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);
            str = r.Replace(str, "");

            //Обрезаем верхний блок навигации
            int positionFirstPagination = str.IndexOf("<h2>");
            if (positionFirstPagination != -1)
                str = str.Substring(positionFirstPagination);

            //Обрезаем нижний блок навигации
            int positionTwoPagination = str.IndexOf("<div class=\"clearfix\"></div><div class=\"reader-pagination\">");
            if (positionTwoPagination != -1)
                str = str.Substring(0, positionTwoPagination);

            //Чистим от оставшихся тегов
            Regex r1 = new Regex("<[^>]*>", RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);
            string textHtml = "";
            textHtml = r.Replace(str, "");
            output.AppendLine(r1.Replace(textHtml,""));
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Произошла ошибка", "Ошибка");
        }
    }
```

И есть кнопка, по которой этот метод вызывается:

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        string pageChapter = Browser.FindElement(By.XPath("//a[@class='first']")).Text; //Количество страниц в главе
        int countPageChapter = Convert.ToInt32(pageChapter);

        //Запускаем цикл для переключения страниц в главе
        Actions action = new Actions(Browser);
        for (int i = 1; i <= countPageChapter; i++)
        {
            html = Browser.FindElement(By.TagName("html")).GetAttribute("outerHTML"); //Получаем исходный код страницы
            StartParser(html); //Запускаем метод
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000); //Задержка
            action.SendKeys(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.Right).Build().Perform(); //Имитируем нажатие клавиши "вправо" для перехода на следующую страницу главы

        }
    }
```

Проблема в том, что если запускать работу этого метода в цикле, то он самую первую страницу главы повторяет 2 раза. И я не могу понять, почему так происходит.
Если без цикла, то все работает хорошо.
Если `StartParser(html)` перенести в самый конец цикла, после `action.SendKeys(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.Right).Build().Perform()`, то вроде как работает правильно, но лишь некоторое время, стоит переключить две-три главы и проблема повторяется снова.
Глобально объявлено следующее:

```
IWebDriver Browser;
string html = "";
StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
```

За основу брал вот эту страницу: https://litnet.com/reader/rassvetnica-2-b69223
Результат получения текста: https://pastebin.com/QfrDEAx5

Там еще можно заметить строчку "23 Вперед". Вот если парсер работает правильно, то ее нет. А если неправильно, то она есть)

Comment: Судя по странице, которую вы парсите, там текст подгружается асинхронно по ссылке на страницу. Очевидно, что `Perform()` не ждет, когда отработает JS код

Comment: @АртёмОконечников, что в таком случае делать? Это первый опыт работы с подобного рода сайтом.

Comment: Можно получить текст глав непосредственно оттуда, откуда их подгружает пейджинг (POST запрос на https://litnet.com/reader/get-page) получите JSON с HTML'ем

Comment: @АртёмОконечников, это будет очень проблематично. Может у Selenium есть метод, позволяющий дождаться полной загрузки страницы?

Comment: Возможно селениум умеет работать с JS, я не в курсе

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Помогу вам немного, но это не selenium (ибо считаю лишним)...

### Определения источника данных

Почти каждый сайт работает по принципу получения тех или иных данных со своих, внутренних API, зачастую это POST запросы с ответом формата JSON. Так и ваш сайт не отличается от этого.

- Для начала запустим инструменты разработчика (обычно это F12 в браузере), либо качаем и запускаем Fiddler. Тут дело вкуса...
- Далее заходим на нужную нам страницу и отлавливаем все запросы/ответы (в браузере это вкладка Network).
- Обычно в браузере подобные данные обозначаются типом XHR (XMLHttpRequest). У меня лично нашло что то вроде этого:

[image: xhr]

Тут мы видим 2 ответа от сервера заблокированных (наверно реклама), один какой то с непонятным названием (да и размер маловат), а вот get-page, вроде оно. Смело тыкаем на него и смотрим ответ!

- В ответе мы видим некую структуру, которая содержит текст, страницы, нормер и кучу всего полезного. Это JSON. То что нужно!

[image: json]

### Отправляем запрос на сервер и получаем результат программно

Раз мы знаем от куда "ноги растут", значит можем смело пытаться получить данные программно!

- Для начала посмотрим на сам запрос (опять же в браузере, либо Fiddler), мы видим:

  - *Request URL* - https://litnet.com/reader/get-page
  - *Request Method* - POST
  - Спускаемся к Request Headers и там:

    - *content-type* - application/x-www-form-urlencoded.
    - Также *cookie* смотрим, пригодятся
  - А также в самом низу смотрим тело Form Data

Все, пока этого нам достаточно для того, что бы составить запрос.

- Пишем простенький код, который будет отправлять POST запрос с телом формата x-www-form-urlencoded:

  ```
  public async Task<string> SendRequest(string url, FormUrlEncodedContent content = null)
  {
      string data;
      var baseAddress = new Uri("https://litnet.com");
      var cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
      using (var handler = new HttpClientHandler { CookieContainer = cookieContainer })
      using (var client = new HttpClient(handler) { BaseAddress = baseAddress })
      {
          cookieContainer.Add(baseAddress, new Cookie("_csrf", "5e0e609cd553bf22a0e9fdd95a4f75889024bd7c2f00777915824ddfabb81457a%3A2%3A%7Bi%3A0%3Bs%3A5%3A%22_csrf%22%3Bi%3A1%3Bs%3A32%3A%22sLir_yrIIA4H6D7vUOR0Xkxw9tC47sBW%22%3B%7D"));

          var result = await client.PostAsync(url, content);
          data = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
      }

      return data;
  }
  ```

Что мы тут видим? А все просто, у нас есть async метод, который принимает `string url`, а также тело (о нем дальше...). Внутри мы задаем базовый адрес и CookieContainer, ну а дальше заполняем все тем, что нам надо и отправляем асинхронно POST запрос с указанным телом и указанными Cookie.

- Заготовка для отправки у нас есть, давайте создадим для удобства еще один метод, который уже будет возвращать нам необходимые данные:

  ```
  public async Task<string> GetData(int page)
  {
      var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
      {
          new KeyValuePair<string, string>("chapterId", "562502"),
          new KeyValuePair<string, string>("page", page.ToString()),
          new KeyValuePair<string, string>("_csrf", "dlFCTUxvWi0FHSs/ExYoZD8QdgV6K21bIx4QfRQEIlpPJQF5exwYeg==")
      });

      return await SendRequest("/reader/get-page", content);
  }
  ```

Тут мы создаем массив FormUrlEncodedContent, который преобразует наши данные в правильный для отправки формат application/x-www-form-urlencoded. Данные для отправки такие же, которые мы видели в Form Data нашего запроса через браузер (убрал лишние, которые вроде как не мешают отправке). То есть мы отправляем id книги, страница и идентификатор _csrf. В результате наш метод асинхронно вернет string с JSON данными.

### Чтение данных

Допустим данные мы теперь можем получить, что же дальше? А дальше нам наши данные нужно преобразовать в нужный нам формат.

- Для всей работы нам понадобится подключить 3 вещи:

  1. *System.Web* (он у вас уже должен быть в системе, вам всего лишь надо его подключить в Reference (ссылки).
  2. *Newtonsoft.Json* - подключается через NuGet
  3. *HtmlAgilityPack* - тоже NuGet.
- Далее пишем код. Я буду писать все внутри обычного Button (событие Click), вы уже сами смотрите что и где... В моем случае на кнопку 2 раза - генерируется код. у кода перед названием меняем `void` на `async void`.
- Объявим в начале `StringBuilder` и 2 `int` переменные, которые будут держать в себе страницы:

  ```
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  int totalPage = 1;
  int currentPage = 0;
  ```
- Далее создадим цикл `while`, который будет выполнятся до тех пор, пока текущая страница не будет равна общему числу страниц:

  ```
  while (totalPage != currentPage)
  {

  }
  ```
- Что мы будем делать внутри цикла? Правильно, получать данные, пока не получим все. Для этого вызовем ранее созданный `GetData`, который должен нам вернуть JSON. Из полученного JSON надо вытянуть страницы (totalPages и page), а также сам текст (data), который в свою очередь добавим в StringBuilder. Ну и что бы сервер не ворчал, поставим паузу. Таким образом весь наш код будет выглядеть примерно следующим образом (тут используется Newtonsoft.Json для удобной работы с JSON):

  ```
  while (totalPage != currentPage)
  {
      var json = JObject.Parse(await GetData(currentPage+1));
      totalPage = (int)json["totalPages"];
      currentPage = (int) json["page"];
      sb.Append((string) json["data"]);
      await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
  }
  ```
- На этом этапе мы имеем StringBuilder, который имеет в себе текст со всех страниц, нам нужно его теперь преобразить в читаемый вид, убрав мусор (который кидает нам сервер для запутывания), а также убрать все HTML теги:

  - Сначала преобразуем все крякозябли в виде `&mdash; &#x414;&#x430;!` в читаемый текст, для этого нам поможет `HttpUtility` из System.Web.:

    ```
    var currentHtml = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(sb.ToString());
    ```
  - Имея чистый HTML код мы воспользуемся дальше вашим методом для удаления мусорных `<span>`:

    ```
    Regex r = new Regex("<span .+? </span> ", RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);
    currentHtml = r.Replace(currentHtml, "");
    ```
  - Ну что, уже почти на финишной прямой! Осталось избавиться от HTML тегов. Для этого отлично подойдет HtmlAgilityPack. Суть проста до безобразия... Мы знаем, что текст находится внутри тега `<p>`, так давайте возьмем все эти теги и из них вытянем драгоценный текст:

    ```
    var html = new HtmlDocument();
    html.LoadHtml(currentHtml);
    var allText = html.DocumentNode.Descendants("p").Select(text => text.InnerText);
    ```
  - Вот и все, на выходе мы имеем чистый массив каждой строчки текста из книги. Переведем в string. По сути старый StringBuilder нам уже не нужен, очистим его, а затем циклом занесем в него построчно все из полученного массива:

    ```
    sb.Clear();
    foreach (var s in allText) sb.AppendLine(s);
    ```
  - Фуф, ну вроде все, весь код будет примерно такой:

    ```
    var currentHtml = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(sb.ToString());
    Regex r = new Regex("<span .+? </span> ", RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);
    currentHtml = r.Replace(currentHtml, "");

    var html = new HtmlDocument();
    html.LoadHtml(currentHtml);
    var allText = html.DocumentNode.Descendants("p").Select(text => text.InnerText);

    sb.Clear();
    foreach (var s in allText) sb.AppendLine(s);
    ```

Ура ура! Можно наслаждаться результатом (я его не буду выводить весь, всего пару строк (первую и последнюю). [Весь текст](https://pastebin.com/pH9ap2zR):

> — Ты очень сильно изменилась в последнее время, Мариш.
>   ////куча текста///
>   Пока остановились на этой идее. Вряд ли речь шла о злобном полтергейсте, но о ком-то, желающем что-то передать самой хозяйке. Если призрак до сих пор в квартире, то это можно будет проверить знаком призыва.

Ну что, надеюсь поможет это все. Желаю удачи и да, не забывайте, что Cookie это дело "сессионное", то есть рано или поздно они у вас "испортятся" и надо будет брать новые, но это уже другая история... А и еще, раз это async, то не стоит и про CancellationToken забывать, но это тоже, захотите - поймете как и что.

А и еще, **что касается цикла while** - данный сайт отдает такое значение, как isLastPage. Можете отказаться от страниц и использовать его.

**Что касается глав** - на последней странице сервер отдает такие данные :

```
"nextChapter": {
  "id": "564038",
  "title": "Глава 2. Старинные фотографии "
}
```

Где вам нужно всего лишь взять id и заменить его в теле запроса. Для удобства перепишите его, с номером страницы в метод передавайте и id книги, ну а дальше также, циклом читайте. Это уже скажем так, домашнее задание...

Comment: спасибо большое, все доходчиво и понятно)

Comment: @АндрейФедоров Да не за что. Рад, что смог помочь!