# Как выполнить js code в asp net mvc?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, webbrowser

Есть html файл,необхадимо его открыть и в нем вызвать функцию и получить результат,в wpf это делалось при помощи webbrowser ,а в asp.net mvc без понятия.

Comment: не совсем ясна суть вопроса, вам нужно открыть сохраненный html, или перейти на страницу? Обычно у контролов в html  есть onload, соответственно на него подвешивать функции в жабаскрипте можно.

Comment: Вообще такой подход не очень правильный (тем более в web). Хотите что то распарсить - ищите запросы, которые отправляются и их эмулируйте; Если у вас просто файл, то что мешает вытянуть из него нужную информацию без открытия и тем более выполнения JS? Ну а если у вас на JS основная логика, то просто перенесите все это в ваш Web проект, ведь в asp.net как раз и используется web/js. Скажем вы можете сделать контрол, который при загрузке будет выполнять этот js скрипт.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ можете пример какой-нибдуь привести?

Comment: @Nikita Пример чего? Я не знаю ваших целей, выше мои догадки того, что вы хотите.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Пример эмуляции запросов к локальному файлу,где и хранится весь код

Comment: @Nikita А что ваш файл делает то? Как там все устроено я же не знаю, вы бы приложили пример. [Вот о каких запросах я имею ввиду](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/818449/220553). Но у вас же простой html файл, так почему бы не сделать для него контрол (как обычная страница проекта) и в разметке загружать весь js по onload событию (или еще какому нибудь)?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Если работать с ним просто в браузере,то он рисуент на странице изборажение затем предлагает сохранить