# Выбор инструмента

Tags: c#

Стоит цель для самообразования, загрузить картинку на файлообменник без API
Просто закинуть файл через форму и получить ссылку.

Знаю что можно это сделать с помощью Selenium, наверно самое простое, но это довольно медленно.

А как ещё можно взаимодействовать (без API) ?

Comment: Вероятно, слать post-запросы.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov думаю, под "без API" подразумевалось и отправка запросов

Comment: Можете посмотреть [данный](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/818449/220553) ответ. Суть банально проста, вам нужно узнать каким запросом отправляются данные на сервер и этот вопрос повторить. К примеру imgur посылает [следующее](https://hastebin.com/fayotadaco.makefile) на сервер, как видим - запрос `POST` на адрес `/upload` с телом `multipart/form-data`. В ответ получаем [JSON](https://hastebin.com/igipiceyuq.json), где видим данные изображения и `album` - наш уникальный id изображения.