# Парсинг с помощью Html Agility Pack

Tags: c#, парсер, htmlagilitypack

Пытаюсь вытащить температуру из html кода страницы:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробую вот такой код:

```
        HtmlDocument hap = new HtmlDocument();
        HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
        HtmlDocument doc = web.Load("http://www.intellicast.com/Local/Weather.aspx?location=RSXX0063");
        HtmlNodeCollection nodes = hap.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("/html/body/div[1]/form/div[1]/div[2]/div[5]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[3]/div[1]/a");
        if (nodes != null)
        {
            foreach (HtmlNode node in nodes)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(node);
            }
        }
        else
            Console.WriteLine("Ничего");
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Но в `nodes` ничего не собирается.
Как я понял, с помощью моего XPath (достал я его с помощью расширения для Firefox) ищется то, что заключено в тег `a`, собственно температура, но он не собирает вообще ничего.

---

У сайта есть свой api, доступ к которому он "не хочет" отдавать просто так. Из этого можно сделать вывод, что температуру просто так не получить

Comment: А как у Вас взаимосвязан `HtmlDocument doc` с другими вызовами и переменными? https://html-agility-pack.net/select-nodes

Comment: А **зачем** вам нужно вытаскивать температуру из html кода страницы? Если вам нужна сводка или прогноз погоды,  думаю, можно найти нормальный веб-сервис с такой информацией, например https://openweathermap.org/api

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В приведенном Вами примере кода есть ошибки. Помимо этого, используемый Вами URL перенаправляет (как минимум запросы из Германии) с `301 Moved Permanently` на wunderground.com. Рабочий пример приведён ниже:

```
var web = new HtmlWeb();
var htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();
string xPath = "//a[@href='/National/Temperature/Current.aspx']";
// или "//a[@title='Temperature']"
string url = "http://www.intellicast.com/Local/Weather.aspx?location=RSXX0063";

htmlDoc.LoadHtml(web.Load(url).Text);
var node = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode(xPath);
```

---

По поводу Вашей задачи...
Парсинг чужой HTML страницы для получения данных требует постоянного сопровождения кода, т.к. (как уже [упомянул](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/927626/182750) EvgeniyZ) может поменяться разметка на сайте, измениться URL, да мало ли может придти в голову владельцам сайта. И если уж вопрос стоит ребром и иначе никак, то (здесь позволю себе не согласиться с EvgeniyZ) привязывайтесь к элементам с Id, а не к классам, т.к. спецификация требует уникальность Id, а класс может быть добавлен хоть к каждому элементу или, как в Вашем случае, используйте уникальные (более или менее) атрибуты.
Если Вам необходимо получать сведения о погоде, то имеется огромное количество сервисов с бесплатным API, например [openweathermap](https://openweathermap.org/appid) (разрешает не более 60 запросов в минуту бесплатно).

Comment: Можно ли как-то находить элемент по title, и если можно подскажите как?

Comment: @Irvin добавил в код ответа.

Comment: Если попробовать вывести температуру в консоль, то выводится пустая строка https://ibb.co/mzRwrND

Comment: @Irvin смотрите в отладчике содержимое `htmlDoc`.

Comment: Значение: `{HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument}` Тип: `HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument`

Comment: @Irvin см. поле Text. Если выводится пустая строка, то значит по указанному XPath не находит элементы. https://photos.app.goo.gl/7diqGJUzfXgzTfi9A

Answer (score 3):

`достал я его с помощью расширения для Firefox` - и зря сделали.
Вы понимаете что у вас он выдал? А выдал он примерно следующее `...div[1]/div[2]/div[5]...` - взять **первый** div / в нем взять **второй** div / в нем взять **пятый** div. Ну и так далее. То есть вся ваша портянка XPatch очень статична, а что будет если вдруг первый div окажется например 10-м? А нечего хорошего!

Правильным решением будет поиск чего то уникального в HTML (например имя или класс) и уже от этого элемента "плясать" дальше.

На скриншоте я вижу уникальное следующее:

```
<div class="Charcoal" ...>
```

Нам уже этого достаточно, что бы взять необходимые значения. Перепишем XPath примерно на следующий:

```
/div[@class='Charcoal']/a
```

Как видите в разы короче, чем у вас и менее статично.
В одно время мне очень сильно помогала [эта](https://devhints.io/xpath) шпаргалка, так что советую!

---

Но вообще я вам советую "парсить" HTML только в крайнем случае. Почти все сайты сейчас имеют динамическую подгрузку данных, они разделяют дизайн и источник данных и делается это обычно при помощи API. Например вот данные, который сайт получает в удобном JSON формате, без лишнего HTML...
Вот вам пару ответов в помощь [один](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/924276/220553) и [два](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/818449/220553).

Comment: Вы не ответили на вопрос.

Comment: @XelaNimed Вы можете всегда ответить сами. Моя основная цель была направить человека в правильное направление, а не сказать ему, что он имеет "очепятку" в коде.