# Отправка и сабмит данных в HTML форму .net

Tags: c#, html, веб-программирование

Есть некий сайт, на нем html форма с определенными полями и кнопка для отправки этой формы, после нажатия которой тебя перенаправляет на другой адрес.

Возможно ли через .net (а если возможно, то как) заполнить эту форму значениями и **нажать** на кнопку, а пользователю просто вернуть url который придет после 
отправки формы.

**UPD**

Когда-то это задача была реализована на java, к сожалению ее использовать я не могу. И не совсем понимаю как сделать аналогию в .net
Вот код реализации:

```
public class HttpURLConnection {

private static final String BASE_URL = "/exampleUrl";
private static final String USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0";

public String sendRequest(STTransferDataStructure transferData) throws Exception {
    Connection connection = 
            Jsoup.connect(BASE_URL).userAgent(USER_AGENT).timeout(10 * 1000).method(Connection.Method.POST);

    connection.data("termCode", transferData.sstermCode);
    connection.data("TotalAmount", transferData.ssTotalAmount);

    Connection.Response response = connection.followRedirects(true).execute();
    return sendNextRequest(response.body());
}

private String sendNextRequest(String data) throws Exception {
    Document dom = Jsoup.parse(data);
    String url = dom.getElementsByTag("form").get(0).attr("action");
    Connection connection = Jsoup.connect(url).userAgent(USER_AGENT).timeout(10 * 1000).method(Connection.Method.POST);
    Elements elements = dom.getElementsByTag("input");
    elements.forEach((element) -> {
        if (!element.attr("type").equals("submit")) {
            connection.data(element.attr("name"), element.val());
        }
    });
    Connection.Response response = connection.followRedirects(true).execute();
    return response.body();
}
```

}

Comment: ну либо программно открывать барузер - это вам надо selenium, либо смотреть какой конкретно запрос уходит на сервер с формой - и писать под него на HttpClient

Comment: Посмотрите [это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/924276/220553) и [это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/818449/220553) и после всего этого я думаю вы без проблем решите свою задачу!