# Ввод данных в поле EO.WebBrowser C#

Tags: c#

Всех приветствую.
Мне нужно вводить определенные данные в текстовые поля сайта после загрузки страницы.

В интернете я нашел только выделение поля через js (EvalScript).
Мне же нужно вводить текст и нажимать на кнопку его отправки. Все это я хотел бы реализовать программно. 
Прошу помощи!

Comment: `Все это я хотел бы реализовать программно` - работайте с запросами (POST/GET). Только в крайнем случае стоит ставить компоненты браузера, эмулировать JS или что-то еще. Научитесь работать с сайтом напрямую!

Comment: Мне нужно вылавливать отправленный мной POST запрос. Для этих целей я и танцую с бубном

Comment: Советую почитать например мои ответы: [1](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/924276/220553), [2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/818449/220553). Там есть вся информация, которая вам потребуется для реализации задуманного.

Comment: Вы не верно поняли. Сайт на своей стороне генерирует заголовки, которые я не могу отправлять.(Неоткуда взять) По этой, собственно, причине GET и POST запросы мне не подходят.
Меня интересует именно отправка запроса через поля ввода сайта. Т.е. реализация сия процесса через JS. В ваших ответах нету информации на этот счет. Там исключительно работа с HTTP/S-протоколом

Comment: `Неоткуда взять` - Сайт же их от куда-то берет, верно? Большинство сайтов работает по принципу "API" запросов, который тайно работают на него. Он туда отправляет запрос, а в ответ получают что там вам надо, "заголовки". Вот вам этот API и надо выяснить. Зачем же вам тут браузер? Также еще есть сайты, которые получают данные при помощи сокетов, ну или по старинке - сразу отдают сгенерированный HTML.

Comment: Эти заголовки генерируются через закриптованный js.
Если вы можете еще расшифровать, собрать в нормальный код и запустить - то я нет. По этому вопрос остается все тем же

Comment: Ну, писать костыли или нет - дело ваше, мое лишь направить вас на верный путь. Да и не зная всей картины я вряд-ли вам чем помогу.