# Как запарсить часть интернет-страницы

Tags: c#, парсер, htmlagilitypack, anglesharp

подскажите как можно запарсить  эту таблицу на C#?
я в C# чуть могу, а вот писать веб страницы вообще нет. 
поэтому не знаю что именно нужно парсить в данном случае и можно ли вообще

https://www.kvg-kiel.de/fahrplan/echtzeit/#?stop=1256&language=de

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Почитайте [это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/924276/220553) и [это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/818449/220553), вам будет вполне достаточно данной информации в работе с данными сайтами. Конкретно указанный вами сайт работает с API, при помощи которого он получает JSON с нужными вам данными.

Comment: Когда в браузере открыт сайт нажимаешь `F12`, открывается панель разработчика, нажимаешь на иконку со стрелкой, указываешь мышью на нужный элемент на странице, получаешь в панеле выделение нужной части html, смотришь какой класс или id там прописан, а после в anglesharp используешь для поиска нужных данных этот класс или id. Вкратце так.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Отлично! Оказалось все так просто! простой JSON...а я уже собрался англешарп распаковывать, а тут / на тебе, все намного удобнее и легче!! спасибо за наводку и подробные ответы в прошлом!! *одобряю*  тут не как не поставить или? )))) спасибо еще  раз

Comment: @Vasa Простого "спасибо" мне достаточно. Удачи в решение вашей задачи!