# Парсинг сайта на C#

Tags: c#

Я начинающий в c# и это мой первый вопрос. Мне нужно взять с этого сайта http://mon.declarant.by/vpto/search Тип, рег. номер, дату регистрации и когда был изменен Статус и сам статус.Парсить обычные сайты я могу, но вот на этом сайте есть кнопка подгрузить еще, которая ставит меня в ступор.Подскажите как это лучше сделать.

Comment: И дополнительно: [этот ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/818449/220553)

Comment: Комментарий уважаемого EvgeniyZ даёт пинок в нужную сторону. Очень похоже, что этот сайт - это так называемое "одностраничное приложение", в котором контент страницы динамически строится джаваскриптом, который запращивает данные с сервера. Хороший способ - "хакнуть" протокол общения клиента с сервером и сэмулировать его. Вообще - не рокет сайенс. Из инструментов при этом очень может помочь Fiddler, а когда дойдет до написания программы на C# - понадоится какой то компонент для rest api json запросов - например, от Newtonsoft

Comment: Ничего "хакать" не нужно, достаточно DevTools открыть (в Chrome это F12). http://mon.declarant.by/api/pto-recs?page=2 - и видим, что подгружаются данные в JSON формате.