# Как нажать кнопку в html документе?

Tags: c#, парсер

Например есть сайт такой [avito.ru](https://www.avito.ru/tver/kommercheskaya_nedvizhimost/2_etazhnoe_zdanie_v_tsentre_tveri_1993549894?src=bp_catalog) тут чтобы получить картинку телефона(ссылку) нужно нажать кнопку.

Проблема в том не знаю как нажать кнопку и получить новый html файл или картинку телефона(ссылку) сразу.

Чтобы не нужно было нажимать на кнопку просто использовал AngleSharp или HtmlAgilityPack.

**Когда кнопка не нажата**

```
<div class="item-phone js-item-phone"> 
  <div class="item-phone-number js-item-phone-number  greenContact_color">
  <a class="button item-phone-button js-item-phone-button button-origin contactBar_greenColor button-origin_full-width button-origin_large-extra item-phone-button_hide-phone item-phone-button_card js-item-phone-button_card contactBar_height" href="#login?authsrc=ps" data-marker="item-phone-button/card" data-side="card">
     Показать телефон
 <span class="item-phone-button-sub-text">8 910 XXX-XX-XX</span>
   
 </a>
 </div>
  </div>
```

**Когда кнопка нажата**

Тут появился тег img в свойстве src находиться картинка.

```
 <div class="item-phone js-item-phone"> 
      <div class="item-phone-number js-item-phone-number  greenContact_color">
      <a class="button item-phone-button js-item-phone-button button-origin button-origin_full-width button-origin_large-extra item-phone-button_card js-item-phone-button_card contactBar_height item-phone-button_with-img contactBar_greyColor" href="#login?authsrc=ps" data-marker="item-phone-button/card" data-side="card">
<img src="data:image/png;base64,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" data-marker=""></a>
    </div>
     
 </div>
```

Comment: `не знаю как нажать кнопку` - не как, забудьте про то, что вы видите. Все кнопочки - это POST/GET запросы на сервер, вот с ними и работайте.

Comment: @ EvgeniyZ  Можете пример показать для наглядности я web программирование 0? Буду очень благодарен.

Comment: [Первый](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/924276/220553), [второй](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/818449/220553)

Comment: @ EvgeniyZ спасибо вам буду изучать

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проанализировал что происходит после нажатия на кнопку и получил такую ссылку

```
https://www.avito.ru/items/phone/1788639091&vsrc=r&searchHash=9bmzmp5ykmcks8os884o00sss4g480o
```

1788639091-это  номер поста получаться что-то такое.

```
{"image64":"data:image/png;base64,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"}
```

Извлекаем если скопировать в браузер получим картинку

```
data:image/png;base64,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
```

Таким образом можно получать телефоны из разных постов.