# Авторизация на web портале из c# приложения

Tags: c#, веб-программирование

Первый запрос проходит, а второй нет. Что я упускаю???

```
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
           
 
            var user = "user";
            var password = "password";
            var cookies = new CookieContainer();
            var proxy = new WebProxy("127.0.0.1:8888");




            var getRequest = new GetRequest()
            {
                Address = "https://wsdemo.laximo.ru/",
                AcceptLanguage = "en-US,en;q=0.7,ru;q=0.3",
                Accept = "text/html, application/xhtml+xml, image/jxr, */*",
                Host = "wsdemo.laximo.ru",
                KeepAlive = true,
                TurnOffProxy = true

            };

        
            var data = $"{{\"user%5Blogin%5D={WebUtility.UrlEncode(user)}&user%5Bpassword%5D={WebUtility.UrlEncode(password)}&user%5Bbackurl%5D=https%3A%2F%2Fwsdemo.laximo.ru%2Findex.php%3Ftask%3Dcatalogs\"}}";


            var postRequest = new PostRequest()
            {
                Data = data,
                Address = $"https://wsdemo.laximo.ru/index.php?task=login&view=login",
                Accept = "text/html, application/xhtml+xml, image/jxr, */*",
                Host = "wsdemo.laximo.ru",
                ContentType = "text/html; charset=UTF-8",
                Referer = "https://wsdemo.laximo.ru/index.php?task=catalogs",
                
                KeepAlive = true,
                Proxy = proxy
            };
            postRequest.AddHeader("Origin", "https://wsdemo.laximo.ru");



            postRequest.Run(ref cookies);


            getRequest = new GetRequest()
            {
                Address = $"https://wsdemo.laximo.ru/index.php?task=catalogs&auth=true",
                AcceptLanguage = "en-US,en;q=0.7,ru;q=0.3",
                Accept = "text/html, application/xhtml+xml, image/jxr, */*",
                Host = "wsdemo.laximo.ru",
                ContentType = "text/html; charset=UTF-8",
                KeepAlive = true,
                Referer = "https://wsdemo.laximo.ru/index.php?task=catalogs",
                Proxy = proxy

            };


            getRequest = new GetRequest()
            {
                Address = $"https://wsdemo.laximo.ru/index.php?task=catalogs&auth=true",
                Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9",
                Host = "wsdemo.laximo.ru",
                ContentType = "text/html; charset=UTF-8",
                KeepAlive = true,
                Referer = "https://wsdemo.laximo.ru/index.php?task=catalogs",
                Proxy = proxy
            };
            getRequest.Run(ref cookies);



         //   Config.Instance.AddLogInfo(getRequest.Response);
        }
    }
}

[![введите сюда описание изображения][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VGFRX.png
```

Comment: Вы делаете уйму лишнего, да и используете старое (WebRequest или что там у вас). В C# сейчас актуален лишь `HttpClient`.

Comment: Использовал вот эту статью для примера. https://vc.ru/dev/159863-avtorizaciya-na-lyubom-web-portale-iz-c-prilozheniya

Comment: Это не меняет мой комментарий. [HttpWebRequest](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.net.httpwebrequest) устарел! И причем уже довольно давно. Автору той статьи стоило бы про это знать. Также он делает кучу лишнего, заголовки `Host`, `KeepAlive` устанавливаются автоматически, `Accept` тоже не имеет в большинстве случаев смысла. То есть уже можно понять, что достаточно установить прокси (если нужен) и адрес с телом, все... `ref cookies` - тоже лишнее, инициализируете один раз клиент и дальше его используете. Я еще молчу про `var data`, это JSON, а формируется так криво...

Comment: @EvgeniyZ если надо дублей в список насыпать - напишите мне здесь коммент, я добавлю, а то я покопался, в глаза больше ничего не бросилось.

Comment: @aepot Я не думаю, что ваш дубликат "дубликат", ибо там куча лишнего и совсем не то, что может помочь человеку в понимании, например, криптография, сохранение и загрузка кук, разбор коллекции кук, зачем это все человеку? Тут достаточно простого понимания как работают запросы, как их отловить и понять, что нужно, а что нет (например [это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/924276/220553)), а также пример того, как правильно использовать `HttpClient` с отправкой запросов (посоветовал бы [это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/818449/220553), но там есть ряд неточностей.).