# Как добавить get запрос?

Tags: c#

Как к этому запросу добавить Get запрос?
Этот Post запрос авторизуется на сайте, а как далеше передать от него куки и сделать GET запрос такого вида (https://wsdemo.laximo.ru/index.php?task=aftermarket&view=findOem&brand=&oem=w9142&options%5B%5D=crosses&options%5B%5D=weights&options%5B%5D=names&options%5B%5D=properties&options%5B%5D=images&Locale=ru_RU)

```
string url = "https://wsdemo.laximo.ru/?task=login&view=login";

            var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
            {
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("user[login]", "login"),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("user[password]", "password"),
            });
            using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Cookie", "PHPSESSID=bd0guojiq900jn7oku6va1ar0g");
                var response = client.PostAsync(url, content);
                var result = response.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

            }
```

Comment: `ReadAsStringAsync().Result;` - серьезно? `HttpClient client = new HttpClient()` - вынесите за пределы метода, используйте один клиент под все вопросы. `.Add("Cookie",` - добавляйте куки в коллекцию кук, а не в заголовок, так вам эту строку надо будет всего раз добавить и все. `добавить Get запрос` - Наверно `client.GetAsync()`?

Comment: Для куки лучше всего использовать один `HttpClient` и присвоить ему новый `CookieContainer`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```cs
private static readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
```

Переиспользуйте клиент, он помнит все ваши куки, если вы не будете на каждый запрос создавать новый клиент. Почитайте [документацию](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=netcore-3.1#examples).

Там зеленым по серому написано

> HttpClient is intended to be instantiated once per application, rather than per-use.

И чуть ниже

> `HttpClient` предназначен для однократного создания экземпляра и повторного использования в течение всего жизненного цикла приложения. При создании экземпляра класса `HttpClient` для каждого запроса будет исчерпано количество сокетов, доступных при высоких нагрузках. Это приведет к ошибкам `SocketException`.

Я вам давал [эту ссылку](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1217351/373567) в [вашем же вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1297564/373567). Там полноценный, рабочий пример, даже показано как куки на диск записать.

`HttpClient` ведет себя как браузер с куками. Если вы авторизовались пост-запросом, и пришла кука в ответе клиенту, он ее кладет в свой контейнер и использует при всех последующих запросах к этому серверу. Точно так же как любой настоящий браузер. Для этого не нужно руками засовывать куки в запросы, клиент сам их подставит туда куда нужно, автоматически.

Всё же, постарайтесь в этот раз почитать про [Асинхронное программирование](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/async). Вызов `Task.Result` по незнанию категорически недопустим. Использовать его можно только тогда (!), когда вы на 100% уверены, что вы знаете что делаете и в курсе, как оно (асинхронно) работает.

Comment: Насчет статики я бы поспорил.

Comment: @こきん ну можно еще фабрику, но это уже другая история, которая для текущей задачи - излишество.