# C# Как продолжить выполнение JavaScript кода после перехода или обновления с помощью CefSharp

Tags: javascript, c#, cefsharp

Мне нужно программно выполнить 3 действия на веб-странице

1. заполнить на сайте текстовое поле
2. нажать на кнопку поиска
   (после этого происходит запрос и страница возвращает мне результаты поиска)
3. нажать на первую ссылку

Если я помещу действия 1 и 2 к примеру в кнопку 1:

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
string jsScript1 = "document.getElementById('story').value=" + '\'' + textFind.Text + '\'' + ";" 
+ "document.querySelector('body > div.wrapper > div.header > div.header44 > div.search_panel > span > form > button').click();";
var task1 = chrome.EvaluateScriptAsync(jsScript1);
task1.Wait();
}
```

И действие 3 в кнопку 2:

```
private void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   string jsScript3 = "document.getElementsByTagName('a')[1].click();";
   var task3 = chrome.EvaluateScriptAsync(jsScript3);
   task3.Wait();
}
```

Все работает идеально. Но я хочу выполнять все эти действия внутри одной кнопки.

Я нашел следующее решение:

```
private async void ButtonFind_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
//Action 1 & 2
string jsScript1 = "document.getElementById('story').value=" + '\'' + textFind.Text + '\'' + ";" 
+ "document.querySelector('body > div.wrapper > div.header > div.header44 > div.search_panel > span > form > button').click();";
await chrome.EvaluateScriptAsync(jsScript1);

//Action3
Thread.Sleep(1000); 
string jsScript3 = "document.getElementsByTagName('a')[2].click();";
await chrome.EvaluateScriptAsync(jsScript3);
}
```

Мне приходится использовать `Thread.Sleep(1000);` потому что в JavaScript после перехода на другую страницу или нажатия на кнопку поиска уничтожает все скрипты, запущенные в данный момент в браузере. Также я считаю что использовать Thread.Sleep или Task.Delay - это не хорошая идея.
Как еще я могу изменить свой код, не используя Thread.Sleep или Task.Delay?

Comment: А вы на 100% уверены, что вам нужен целый браузер для парсинга сайта? Просто обычно, люди думают, что это единственный верный вариант, не разбираясь как устроен сайт.

Comment: EvgeniyZ, а что Вы предлагаете сделать?

Comment: А все зависит от сайта, того как он работает и что именно на нем вам надо сделать. Без этого, что либо конкретно советовать не могу. Проанализируйте сайт самостоятельно, определите что и куда он отсылает, ведь почти все сайты это клиенты для некого сервиса, куда они шлют POST/GET запросы.

Comment: EvgeniyZ, покажите пожалуйста пример как парсить без браузера?

Comment: Сайт является тайной? Если нет, давайте ссылку и что надо получить.

Comment: EvgeniyZ, с этого сайта https://kinogo.la,  я хочу получить список всех серии сериала Игра в кальмара, потом если мне понадобится получить информацию о другом сериале чтобы можно было изменить поиск

Comment: Ок, заходим на нужную страницу, где надо достать данные, далее жмем `F12` и открываем вкладку `Сеть`, обновляем страницу и видим все запросы, что отправил браузер и куда. Нажимаем на любой и жмем там `Ctrl+F`, пишем интересующее нас слово, например `1 серия`, браузер из всех запросов выдаст те, где встречается это слово, жмем 2 раза по найденному, и он [выделит](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u1DzL.png) строку с этими данными. По виду это JSON, скопируем все после `=` и до `;`, вставим это в любой обозреватель JSON, ну и увидим там [это](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5qRxk.png), вот вам и все серии.

Comment: То есть, вам надо взять HTML страницы при помощи простого `HttpClient`, далее из нее вытянуть любым удобным способом этот JSON, распарсить его и все, у вас на руках список серий, от кого он и прямые ссылки на просмотр. Еще вариант, там вон есть кнопка "Скачать", жмем на нее также с открытой вкладкой "Сеть", увидим там простой GET запрос на адрес `https://kinogo.la/engine/ajax/cdn_download.php?news_id=33972`, который отдает простенькую HTML страничку со всеми ссылками, всеми сериями и прочей информацией. Также, `HttpClient`, отправляем запрос, парсим, профит. Нужен ли для этого браузер?)

Comment: Как материал для изучения, можете почитать мои старые ответы: [1](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/924276/220553) и [2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/818449/220553).

Comment: Спасибо! Попробую по вашему методу, если возникнут вопросы потом еще напишу вам)

Comment: Вы умеете писать java скрипты для cefSharp?

Comment: И опять 25... Зачем вас целый браузер и скрипты на другом языке? Вы тогда уж сначала говорите что конкретно делаете, а уж затем будем думать, как лучше поступить, ибо вон выше я даже пример вам дал, где нужен чисто C# да и все. Если так "в лоб" отвечать, то нет, я этой ерундой не занимался и как то не очень хочу.