# C# взаимодействие с сайтом из приложения

Tags: c#, winforms, веб-программирование, visual-studio

Делаю приложение в Win Form. В нем необходимо реализовать взаимодействие с сайтом. То есть, нужно достать от туда некоторую информацию(на скрине выделена красной рамкой), но суть в том что я даже не представляю как можно взаимодействовать с этим сайтом из приложения.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/924276/220553 и https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/818449/220553 в помощь.

Comment: Для начала стоит узнать, что такое HTTP, потом позракомиться с инструментами разработчика в браузере, и только пооом брать класс `HttpClient` и работать с ним в приложении.